# Can a table be locked by another table?

Tags: oracle, locking, ora-00054

We're encountering issues on our oracle 11g database, regarding table lock.

We have a procedure that is executed via sql*plus, which truncates a table, let say table1.
We sometimes get a ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT error during execution of the procedure at the part when the table is to be truncated. We have a webapp that is in a tomcat server, which when restarted (to kill sessions to the database from tomcat), the procedure can be re executed successfully.
table1 isn't used, not even in select, in the source code for the webapp, but a lot of parent table of table1 is.

So is it possible that an uncommitted update to one of its parent table is causing the lock?. If so, any suggestions on how I can test it?
I've checked with the DBA during times when we encounter the issue, but he can't get the session that is blocking the procedure and the statement that caused the lock.

Comment: See:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842765/ora-00054-resource-busy-and-acquire-with-nowait-specified-or-timeout-expired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an update of a parent table will get a lock on the child table.  Below is a test case demonstrating it is possible.

Finding and tracing a specific intermittent locking issue can be painful.  Even if you can't trace down the specific conditions it would be a good idea to modify any code to avoid concurrent DML and DDL.  Not only can it cause locking issues, it can also break `SELECT` statements.

If removing the concurrency is out of the question, you may at least want to enable DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT so that the `truncate` statement will wait for the lock instead of instantly failing: `alter session set ddl_lock_timeout = 100000;`

```
--Create parent/child tables, with or without an indexed foreign key.
create table parent_table(a number primary key);
insert into parent_table values(1);
insert into parent_table values(2);
create table child_table(a number references parent_table(a));
insert into child_table values(1);
commit;

--Session 1:  Update parent table.
begin
    loop
        update parent_table set a = 2 where a = 2;
        commit;
    end loop;
end;
/

--Session 2:  Truncate child table.  Eventulaly it will throw this error:
--ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired
begin
    loop
        execute immediate 'truncate table child_table';
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

> any suggestions on how I can test it?

You can check the **blocking sessions** when you get `ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT` error.

Blocking sessions occur when one sessions holds an **exclusive lock** on an object and doesn't release it before another sessions wants to update the same data. This will block the second until the first is either does a **COMMIT** or **ROLLBACK**.

```
SELECT
   s.blocking_session, 
   s.sid, 
   s.serial#, 
   s.seconds_in_wait
FROM
   v$session s
WHERE
   blocking_session IS NOT NULL;
```

For example, see my similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29513602/3989608) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29604501/3989608).